# Linq to Sql General Help - Insert Statement

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, insert

I am currently trying to create a new order (which will be shown below) in a web service, and then send that data to insert a new row into the database. For some reason my DBML / Data Context does not allow me to use InsertOnSubmit.

Any ideas? I haven't used Linq to Sql in about 7 months.

Thanks in advance.

```
[WebMethod]
    public string InsertOrderToDatabases()
    {
        //Start Data Contexts ------
        DataContext db = new DataContext(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["RainbowCMSConnectionString"]);
        DataContext dcSqlOES = new DataContext(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["OESConnectionString"]);

        //Get table from local database
        Table<Schedule> Schedule = db.GetTable<Schedule>();

        //Find last order number in databases
        var lastOrderNumber = from lOrder in Schedule
                              orderby lOrder.templ_idn descending
                              select lOrder.templ_idn;

        int firstOrderID;
        var firstOrder = lastOrderNumber.FirstOrDefault();
        firstOrderID = firstOrder.Value + 1;

        qrOrder qrOrd = new qrOrder
        {
            .... data in here creating a new order

        };

        //TODO: fix below with an insert on submit
        if (qrOrd != null)
        {
        //    **Schedule.InsertOnSubmit(qrOrd);**
        }
        //db.GetTable<Schedule>().InsertOnSubmit(qrOrd);

        try
        {
            //Submit the changes to the database
            db.SubmitChanges();
            return "Orders were sent to the databases.";
        }
        catch ()
        {

        }
    }
```

Comment: What does "doesn't let me" mean? What error are you getting?

Comment: Have you tried simply using `db.Schedule.InsertOnSubmit(qrOrd);`, as done in the example on MSDN? (Note: table may be Schedules or some other name.) http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb763516.aspx

Comment: I will get the following error when I try to use "Schedule.InsertOnSubmit(qrOrd);":
Error: The best overloaded method match for 'System.Data.Linq.Table<Web_Service.Schedule>.InsertOnSubmit(Web_Service.Schedule)' has some invalid arguments. @JonSenchyna, I have tried this. For some reason my Datacontext isn't cooperating. It should be db.Schedules.InsertOnSubmit like you said. But no luck for me.

Comment: What parameter type is Schedule.InsertOnSubmit() expecting?  It should be a strongly typed entity matching the entries that your table expects.  Is it possible that you're attempting to insert into the wrong table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your response, it appears that you are using the wrong table, or perhaps the wrong data type.  I also noticed that when you declare your local`Schedule` variable, you declare it as type `Table<Schedule>`, which means it should contain `Schedule` entities, not `qrOrder` entities.

[`Table<TEntity>.InsertOnSubmit`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb763516.aspx) expects a specific strongly typed entity to be passed in.  In your case, it is expecting `Web_Service.Schedul‌e`, but you are trying to pass in a `qrOrder`.

Comment: Thanks Jon. I should have noticed I wasn't using Schedule as my entity. I made a new class for qrOrder without noticing, and kept wondering why it wouldn't work.

Answer (score 0):

```
 Schedule.InsertOnSubmit(qrOrd);
```

That line will not treat to submit changes to connected entity  , Try this

```
    db.Schedule.InsertOnSubmit(qrOrd);
    db.SubmitChanges();
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try with

```
db.GetTable(typeof(Schedule)).InsertOnSubmit(qrOrd);
```

Or

```
 db.GetTable(qrOrd.GetType()).InsertOnSubmit(qrOrd);
```